# Group by and head(1) in R and preserve list names in group_map

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

(Using mtcars for reproducibility)

First question: why does below return one row & not one row per group.

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  head(1)
```

Second Question: I can do this to get above but issue here is the name of my list (cyl name) is not preserved, how can I get that preserved.

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  group_map(~head(.x,1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`head` is a base R function which doesn't know how to respect the grouping done by `dplyr` functions. There are `dplyr` functions which allow you to do this so use them.

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% slice(1)

#   mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  22.8     4   108    93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
#2  21       6   160   110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
#3  18.7     8   360   175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
```

To answer your second question unlike base `split` `dplyr` functions don't give names to the list so you can assign them later. You can use :

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  group_map(~head(.x,1)) %>%
  setNames(unique(sort(mtcars$cyl)))

#$`4`
# A tibble: 1 x 10
#    mpg  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  22.8   108    93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1

#$`6`
# A tibble: 1 x 10
#    mpg  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1    21   160   110   3.9  2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4

#$`8`
# A tibble: 1 x 10
#    mpg  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  18.7   360   175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
```

Comment: Thanks for answering first one, I dont think you got my second question. I want cyl name as my list name (4,6,8) not random 1,2,3

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to not reference mtcars again in last line. Its actually piped a lot & my dataframe is not same that I can hardcode dataset name like you have done in setnames line

Comment: What I would actually do is : `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% slice(1L) %>% split(.$cyl)` if you really want them as named list. Would that help?

Comment: A simpler trick to preserve the grouping variable name is to create a duplicate column of the grouping variable. In your code: `mtcars %>% mutate(cyl2=cyl) %>% group_by(cyl2) %>% group_map(~head(.x,1)) %>% bind_rows()`

Answer (score 1):

Illustrating what I have mentioned in the comment (regarding your second question):

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(cyl2=cyl) %>%
  group_by(cyl2) %>%
  group_map(~head(.x,1)) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

Output:

```
    mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  22.8     4   108    93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
2  21       6   160   110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
3  18.7     8   360   175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
```